# properties of flash ADS

Tags: flash

Hi I got a general qustion regarding flah ads

In our current HtML website the bottom of the page i have three Iframes and these for getting ADVERTISEMENTS.
I am getting adds from third parties.
I have a simple modal pop up using jquery on this page and when I pull this pop up to the bottom of the page where I have I frames which generate adds some flash adds are actually coming as the top layerof this popup.so the content in the popup is overlapped by this image 
why is this happening and what suggestions should I send to the third parties which will make their flash adds not to over lap the pop up I created please let me know thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Flash has a property called "windowing mode" or "wmode" for short. This controls how the flash object is rendered by the browser. The default mode "window" causes the flash object to render on top of any other element on the page, regardless of frames or z-index.

You want to get your 3rd-party flash object to render using `wmode=opaque` or `wmode=transparent` so that it will render correctly in the browser and respect z-index order (the different between these two modes is whether content that is under the flash object can be seen through transparent areas of the flash).

See this [Adobe knowledge base article](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html#optional) for details.

*edit:* If you control the iframe content, you can force this mode yourself.